# Why is react native bundling multiple times?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I use a custom dev client for ios and expo.

Everytime I use the simulator and reload my ios app bundles multiple times and I can't figure out why.

Also this leads to unexpected crashes when using remote debugging.

[image: Terminal Screenshot]

This is my package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "test": "jest --watch",
    "test-coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "testChanged": "jest --watch --coverage=false --changedSince=origin/master",
    "testDebug": "jest -o --watch --coverage=false",
    "testFinal": "jest",
    "updateSnapshots": "jest -u --coverage=false"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "6.0.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^13.0.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^13.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "^13.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^13.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.10",
    "@react-navigation/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",
    "agora-rn-uikit": "^3.3.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "eas-cli": "^0.43.0",
    "expo": "^43.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "~1.2.1",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "~4.0.3",
    "expo-dev-client": "^0.6.3",
    "expo-facebook": "~12.0.3",
    "expo-image-picker": "~11.0.3",
    "expo-keep-awake": "^10.0.1",
    "expo-linking": "~2.4.2",
    "expo-secure-store": "~11.0.3",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.13.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.1.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~1.0.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.10.13",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "jest-expo": "~43.0.1",
    "native-base": "^3.3.7",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-agora": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.8.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-navigation-header-buttons": "^7.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^4.0.4",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^9.1.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "babel-jest": "^27.3.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|react-native-vector-icons|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg)"
    ],
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "!**/coverage/**",
      "!**/node_modules/**",
      "!**/babel.config.js",
      "!**/jest.setup.js"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/jest/setup.js"
    ]
  },
  "private": true,
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

I just found similar questions but no answers.

I also tried cleaning the npm cache, but with no luck

Thank you in advance!